# Sequence ${2n}\cdot p_{2n}+1$ (counting of different prime factors)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Sequence ${2n}\cdot p_{2n}+1$ for $n=1,2,...20$ is

$7,29,79,3^2 \cdot 17,3 \cdot 97,5\cdot 89,3^2 \cdot 67, 3 \cdot 283, 7 \cdot157,7^2\cdot29,37\cdot47,2137,37\cdot71,3^4 \cdot 37,33917 \cdot 599,29 \cdot 163,5437,3 \cdot 5 \cdot7 \cdot59,3^2 \cdot769$

If we denote with $\operatorname {diff}(n)$ the number of different prime factors of $n$ then we have for the first $20$ members of a  sequence ${2n}\cdot p_{2n}+1$

$1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,4,2$

I am interested in what happens for very big $n$´s, more precisely, is it impossible that we have $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \dfrac {|\{\operatorname {diff}(2k \cdot p_{2k}+1)=1  \text{or}\operatorname {diff}(2k \cdot p_{2k}+1)=2:k=1,...,n \}|}{n}=1?$$

And, is it possible that we have

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \dfrac {|\{\operatorname {diff}(2k \cdot p_{2k}+1)=1  \text{or}\operatorname {diff}(2k \cdot p_{2k}+1)=2:k=1,...,n \}|}{n}=0?$$

The expression in numerator is just the cardinality of all the numbers in the set $\{2\cdot p_2+1,...,2n \cdot p_{2n}+1\}$ that have either $1$ or $2$ different prime factors, so this limit measures the density.

If someone of you pushes these calculations much further, let me know.

Peter calculated that $2646448$ times the expression has at most two prime factors upto $n = 10^7$, which is, I think, a very high percent because much of these numbers should be divisible with $3$.

Comment: In short, you want to measure the density of the positive integers $n$ such that $$\omega(2n\cdot p_{2n}+1)\le 2$$ where $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime and $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, right ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is true now.

Comment: In the range $1\le n\le 10^4$ , we have $5983$ positive integers for which condition is not satisfied (the expression has more than $2$ distinct prime factors)

Comment: @Peter So, the limit seems to not only not be equal to 1 (as expected), but could be equal to zero?

Comment: This would be even plausible because large numbers usually have more than $2$ distinct prime factors. Typically, the number of distinct ptime factors of $n$ is $\log(\log(n))$

Comment: @Peter Yes I know, but this sequence has special form. How many primes did you find in that range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95327/discussion-between-peter-and-gresnik).